How to check if a char is present two times in an array of char in c?
I wanted to check if one char is present in an array of char twice, but strchr() will return the position of the first occurring char.
I was thinking of slicing the array like Python does arr[3:], considered from the 3rd element onward. Does C have such a capability?
if not, what is the best solution for this problem?
Shall I make it myself with for loop, if else, and global variables?

The (somewhat) equivalent to pythons arr[3:] is &arr[3] or arr + 3

To be clear, this slice shares memory with the original array, it's not a copy like a python slice. But if you're just reading the array, not modifying it, they're equivalent.

Are you asking if a particular character is present twice? Or any character? Give an example.

"but strchr() will return the position of the first occurring char" - perfect, so char *p; int count = 0; while ((p = strchar (str, char))) { p += 1; count += 1 } ??

@tkausl so if I say if (strchr(arr[3], chr); will return any occurance of chr after the 3rd element?

@Schwern the problem is that I should have all the alphabet in the list of size 26 from the user regardless of their case, and I have to check if any character is repeated twice.
is it okay to give the example in the comment or shall I edit the question?

@BKazimy You want to know if any character repeats twice. Edit the question, please. Give an example.

Just to be clear, does that have to be present exactly two times or at least two times?

@alex01011 Actually I want all characters of the English alphabet to be there once, and I'm checking if any are repeated.

@BKazimy: In that case, I rather suggest that you create an array arr of 26 bool elements and initialize them to false. The element arr[0] will specify whether 'a' was encountered, arr[1] will specify whether 'b' was encountered and arr[25] will specify whether 'z' was encountered. You can then loop over all characters of the string and then set the array elements accordingly. If an array element was already true when you try to set it, then you know that you have a duplicate character. After looping over all characters, you can verify that all elements are true.

@BKazimy: Do you happen to be doing the Substitution assignment of CS50? I am asking because in that assignment, one of the things that you must do is exactly what you describe.

@BKazimy: If the string contains the characters 'a' and 'A' both once, should they be considered different characters or duplicate characters?

I reverted the edit.  This was not a clarification, but a completely different question.  The original question was about "one char" (not checking whether there was any duplicate) and had nothing about the alphabet (most ASCII characters are non-alphabetic) and certainly not case-insensitivity.  In such cases, you should simply ask a 2nd question.

@AndreasWenzel yes, you got me, Im doing exactly as you said, the Substitution assignment of CS50. Well 'a' and 'A' are supposed to be treated as same in the key phrase and the case order shall be maintained as in plaintext, so that's why Im asking if strchr() is case sensitive or not.

Thanks @MatthewFlaschen, for reverting the edit, and I think I can find my way out from this bug on to the end of the problem.

@BKazimy: In that case, my answers probably are confusing for you, because I am using pointers (e.g. char *) in them. You will only learn about pointers in week 4. However, the function strchr should be equally confusing to you, because it also uses pointers. You can replace all occurrances of char * with string and #include <cs50.h>, and it should make more sense to you.

@BKazimy: If you want to make strchr case-sensitive, then you have to convert the entire string to upper-case or lower-case beforehand, or you have to call strchr twice, once for the upper-case version of the character and once for the lower-case version, and then take the result that comes first.

You can only use strchr on strings but nothing in your question indicates that you are dealing with a string. But rather you are dealing with an array of characters...? Then memchr is the correct function to use.

@BKazimy: Generally, I recommend that you rather ask your questions about CS50x on the Discord CS50 server rather than Stack Overflow, because Stack Overflow will give you general answers to your questions, whereas the Discord CS50 server will give you answers tailored to your particular assignment without spoiling the problem for you, and without using syntax that you will only learn in a later week.

NOTE: This is an answer to revision 1 of the question, which asked how to determine whether a single character occurrs more than once. Meanwhile, the question has been changed to ask how to determine whether any character occurs more than once. I have therefore answered the latest version of the question in a separate answer. EDIT: At the time of this writing, the question has reverted back to revision 1.

but strchr() will return the position of the first occurring char.

You can call strchr twice. The second call will find the second character, if it exists. Here is an example:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool does_char_exist_twice( const char *str, char c )
{
    const char *p;

    // try to find first occurrence of character, returning
    // false on failure
    p = strchr( str, c );
    if ( p == NULL )
        return false;

    // make p point one past the first occurrence
    p++;

    // try to find second occurrence of character
    p = strchr( p, c );

    // return true if second occurrence found, otherwise false
    return p != NULL;
}

void perform_check_and_print_result( const char *str, char c )
{
    // call the function "does_char_exist_twice" and print the result
    printf(
        "The character '%c' DOES %s exist at least twice in \"%s\".\n",
        c,
        does_char_exist_twice(str, c) ? "   " : "NOT",
        str
    );
}

int main( void )
{
    perform_check_and_print_result( "ab"  , 'a');
    perform_check_and_print_result( "aba" , 'a');
    perform_check_and_print_result( "abc" , 'a');
    perform_check_and_print_result( "abca", 'a');
}

This program prints the following output:
The character 'a' DOES NOT exist at least twice in "ab".
The character 'a' DOES     exist at least twice in "aba".
The character 'a' DOES NOT exist at least twice in "abc".
The character 'a' DOES     exist at least twice in "abca".


So that means in case I were to be sure of the character existing once, I can do this too?
return (strchr(str, strchr(str, c)++)? true: false;

@BKazimy: That code that you posted in your comment will likely crash if finding the first character fails. You are not allowed to pass a NULL pointer to strchr, as that will invoke undefined behavior.

So apart from finding the first char being null, others are okay?
Hey I know the position of the first char, so I can do return strchr(str, c+index)? true: false;  or maybe just return strchr(str, c+index);

@BKazimy: You cannot use ++ on the return value of strchr, as that is not a variable. You can only use ++ on a variable (or on a modifiable lvalue, to be precise). However, you can write +1 instead.

@BKazimy: I believe you mean strchr(str + index + 1, c) instead of strchr(str, c+index). Yes, that would be correct.

this only works for one character, the OP wants to check for any duplicates

@Schwern defenestrated the program into a for loop and it did exactly as expected.
Thanks all.

@BKazimy See my revised answer for a more efficient solution.

hey @AndreasWenzel is the strchr() case sensitive?

@BKazimy: Yes, it is. That is why I asked you in a comment to your question whether you wanted your program to be case-sensitive or not. You have not answered that question yet.

@AndreasWenzel so how do you think I should tackle the problem down? any algorithm that you suggest? and yes as for the answer to our question, the alphabet array is case insensitive but the caseing order of message that I shall encrypt shall remain as original.

@BKazimy: Meanwhile, I have answered the latest version of your question (before it was reverted) in a separate answer.

@AndreasWenzel appreciate the effort; you really do bless your students.

@Schwern: I was answering revision 1 of the question. Revision 2 of the question asked a significantly different question, which I answered in a separate answer. Afterwards, someone else reverted the question back to revision 1.

NOTE: This is an answer to revision 2 of the question, which asked how to determine whether any character in a string occurs more than once. Meanwhile, the question has been reverted back to revision 1, which asked how to determine whether a single character occurs more than once. See my other answer for an answer to that question.
A simple, but inefficient way to solve the problem is to

load the first character, and compare that character with all characters that come after that character in the string, and then
load the second character and compare that character with all characters that come after that character in the string, and then
load the third character and do the same, and then
keep repeating until you reach the end of the array.

Here is an example:
// This function will return `true` if any duplicates were found,
// otherwise false.
bool check_for_duplicates_inefficiently( const char *str )
{
    int length = strlen( str );

    for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = i + 1; j < length; j++ )
        {
            if ( str[i] == str[j] )
                return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

A more efficient solution is to create an array arr of 26 bool elements (one for every character of the English alphabet) and to initialize them to false. The element arr[0] will specify whether 'a' was encountered, arr[1] will specify whether 'b' was encountered and arr[25] will specify whether 'z' was encountered.
You can then loop over all characters of the string and then set the array elements accordingly.
If an array element was already true when you try to set it, then you know that you have a duplicate character. After looping over all characters, you can verify that all elements are true.
Here is an example:
// This function will return `true` if any duplicates were found,
// otherwise false.
bool check_for_duplicates_efficiently( const char *str )
{
    // initialize array elements to 0/false
    bool letters[26] = {0};

    int length = strlen( str );

    for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ )
    {
        int c = (unsigned char)str[i];

        if ( isalpha( c ) )
        {
            c = toupper( c );

            int offset = c - 'A';

            if ( letters[offset] )
                return true;

            letters[offset] = true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

Note that this answer is assuming that all characters in the string are English alphabetical letters, and that the default locale is being used.
Also note that this solution only works in character sets in which the characters A to Z are contiguous. This is the case with ASCII, and most character sets are ASCII-compatible. However, it is not the case with some uncommon character sets, such as EBCDIC.
Here is a test function of both funtions:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// This function will return `true` if any duplicates were found,
// otherwise false.
bool check_for_duplicates_inefficiently( const char *str )
{
    int length = strlen( str );

    for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = i + 1; j < length; j++ )
        {
            if ( str[i] == str[j] )
                return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

// This function will return `true` if any duplicates were found,
// otherwise false.
bool check_for_duplicates_efficiently( const char *str )
{
    // initialize array elements to 0/false
    bool letters[26] = {0};

    int length = strlen( str );

    for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ )
    {
        int c = (unsigned char)str[i];

        if ( isalpha( c ) )
        {
            c = toupper( c );

            int offset = c - 'A';

            if ( letters[offset] )
                return true;

            letters[offset] = true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

void perform_check_and_print_result( const char *str, int spacing )
{
    bool results[2];

    results[0] = check_for_duplicates_inefficiently( str );
    results[1] = check_for_duplicates_efficiently( str );

    spacing = spacing - strlen( str ) + 1;
    if ( spacing < 0 )
    spacing = 0;

    if ( results[0] != results[1] )
    {
        printf(
            "Both functions disagree on whether the string %*c%s\" "
            "contains duplicates.\n",
            spacing,
            '\"',
            str
        );
    }
    else
    {
        printf(
            "Both functions agree that the string %*c%s\" DOES "
            "%s contain duplicate characters.\n",
            spacing,
            '\"',
            str,
            results[0] ? "   " : "NOT"
        );
    }
}


int main( void )
{
    perform_check_and_print_result( "ab"  , 4 );
    perform_check_and_print_result( "aba" , 4 );
    perform_check_and_print_result( "abc" , 4 );
    perform_check_and_print_result( "abca", 4 );
    perform_check_and_print_result( "abcb", 4 );
    perform_check_and_print_result( "abcc", 4 );
    perform_check_and_print_result( "abcd", 4 );
}

This program has the following output:
Both functions agree that the string   "ab" DOES NOT contain duplicate characters.
Both functions agree that the string  "aba" DOES     contain duplicate characters.
Both functions agree that the string  "abc" DOES NOT contain duplicate characters.
Both functions agree that the string "abca" DOES     contain duplicate characters.
Both functions agree that the string "abcb" DOES     contain duplicate characters.
Both functions agree that the string "abcc" DOES     contain duplicate characters.
Both functions agree that the string "abcd" DOES NOT contain duplicate characters.


hey @Andreas im asking this coz you seem to have passed the cs50s substitution assignment, I passed all the checkpoints except two: :( handles lack of key     failed to execute program due to segmentation fault :( handles too many arguments     timed out while waiting for program to exit it seems that I cant understand, can you enlighten me  ?

@BKazimy: The assignment states the following: "If your program is executed without any command-line arguments or with more than one command-line argument, your program should print an error message of your choice (with printf) and return from main a value of 1 (which tends to signify an error) immediately." -- You appear to not be doing this.

Got it. Thanks to your helps.

A simple solution would be to combine strchr and strrchr:

strchr will return a pointer to the first occurrence of the character
strrchr will return a pointer to the last occurrence of the character

Shall the pointers be equal, then either the character doesn't exist (both calls returned null) or it only exists once (both pointers point to the same character).
#include <string.h>

int char_exists_twice(const char *s, char c) {
    // probably a good idea to check if s is null as well
    const char *first = strchr(s, c);
    const char *last  = strrchr(s, c);

    return first != last;
}



I have to take input from users of all English alphabet, and I should make sure the user did not type any character twice. (case-insensitively)

strchr will only find one character at a time. You're looking for many characters. You could repeatedly call strchr, but this is inefficient as it has to rescan the string for each character.
Instead, scan the string once and keep a count of how many times each character is seen. In Python you'd use a dict, but C doesn't have those. Instead, use an array wide enough to store every letter.
#include <ctype.h>

int first_repeat_letter(const char *string)
{
    // Initialize the count array to all zeros.
    int char_counts[26] = {0};
    for (int i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        // Ignore case.
        int c = tolower(string[i]);

        // Ignore non-letters.
        if (!isalpha(c))
        {
            continue;
        }

        // This converts the letters to a number between 0 and 25.
        // 'a' - 'a' = 0, 'b' - 'a' = 1, 'z' - 'a' = 25.
        int idx = c - 'a';
        char_counts[idx]++;

        // Return the index where the duplicate was found.
        if (char_counts[idx] >= 2)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

By returning the index the caller can find the duplicate letter.
#include <stdio.h>

char string[] = "abcdef1123";
int i = first_repeat_letter(string);
if (i < 0)
{
    printf("No repeats found in '%s'\n", string);
}
else
{
    printf("Repeat char found in '%s': '%c' at %d\n", string, string[i], i);
}

Demonstration.

Actually I want all characters of the English alphabet to be there once, and I'm checking if any are repeated.

This can easily be adapted to that as well. Iterate through char_count and verify each element is 1.
